# 3dsMax to Mudbox - Import Warning: UV not a complete set

Tags: models, 3dsmax, uv-mapping, import

I'm exporting my 3dsMax model to Mudbox. The import gives me a warning that the UV set is incomplete.

First, what does this mean?  That I haven't got all the UVs unwrapped?  Web searches have brought nothing.

Also if this is the problem, is there a way to check if all UVs are unwrapped?

I'll post my map if you need it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like sometimes mudbox gets angry when the unwrap has zero-area faces (not correctly unwrapped) or you have UVs too close to the edge of the map. Can you shrink them all down towards the center (0.5, 0.5) and try again?

Comment: Thanks Steven, I tried your suggestion and it was quickly resolved.  Thanks very much for your advice.  Much appreciated.